# iText Sharp Throwing XML Error When Field Names Have Two Pound Signs

Tags: c#, itext

I'm experiencing a strange error with iText when trying to set the value for a field name that contains two pound signs.  The problem is that I do not have control over the original form field names.

Anyone happen to know how to get around this?  I have tried renaming the fields, but it is not taking the field rename.

This will error out

```
form.SetField("form1[0].#subform[8].#area[12].Line4_FirstName3[4]", "Bill");
```

But if the field name is similar but with only one pound sign it does not

```
form.SetField("form1[0].#subform[8].Line4_FirstName3[4]", "Bill");
```

Exception of type 'System.Web.HttpUnhandledException' was thrown. ---> System.Xml.XmlException: The '#' character, hexadecimal value 0x23, cannot be included in a name.
   at System.Xml.XmlDocument.CheckName(String name)
   at System.Xml.XmlElement..ctor(XmlName name, Boolean empty, XmlDocument doc)
   at System.Xml.XmlDocument.CreateElement(String prefix, String localName, String namespaceURI)
   at System.Xml.XmlDocument.CreateElement(String name)
   at iTextSharp.text.pdf.XfaForm.Xml2SomDatasets.InsertNode(XmlNode n, String shortName)
   at iTextSharp.text.pdf.AcroFields.SetField(String name, String value, String display)
   at iTextSharp.text.pdf.AcroFields.SetField(String name, String value)

This is from iText 4.1.2.0.

When I try to rename the field to remove the second pound sign type test around "#area[12]" it does not rename.

```
PdfReader reader2 = new PdfReader(pdfTemplate);
using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(TemporaryFile, FileMode.Create)) {
PdfStamper stamper = new PdfStamper(reader2, fs);
AcroFields pdfForm = stamper.AcroFields;
//Dim de As New DictionaryEntry
foreach (DictionaryEntry de in pdfForm.Fields) {
    pdfForm.RenameField(de.Key.ToString(), Guid.NewGuid().ToString("N"));
}

stamper.Close();
```

}

Comment: You're filling out an XFA form as if it's an AcroForm. An answer to this question could take 5 to 10 pages. Unfortunately, I don't have the time to write 5 to 10 pages on this subject right now.

Comment: Thanks Bruno.  This is a great hint / information.  I had forgotten about this form style after working with AcroForms for so long.  Now, I'll have to handle both.

Answer (score 0):

I hade the same problem and i worked my way around, setting a name for the MasterPage where the field belongs (in LiveCycle).
This way i no longer have the second "#" on the field name , so i change the name the problem no longer exist.

In your case, try get the full name of the field.

```
PdfReader reader2 = new PdfReader(pdfTemplate);
using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(TemporaryFile, FileMode.Create)) 
{
   PdfStamper stamper = new PdfStamper(reader2, fs);
   AcroFields pdfForm = stamper.AcroFields;

   //Dim de As New DictionaryEntry
   foreach (DictionaryEntry de in pdfForm.Fields) {
       //try this...
       var fullname= fields.GetTranslatedFieldName(de.Key.ToString());
       pdfForm.RenameField(fullname, Guid.NewGuid().ToString("N"));
   }

   stamper.Close();
```

Answer (score 0):

I know that the question is old. But maybe my answer will help someone.
In the question ReplaceField function doesn't work because it can change only the last part of names (all after the last doth in field name).
For this case the following code will work:

```
Dictionary<string, string> changedFields = new Dictionary<string, string>();
foreach (string fieldName in formFields.Fields.Keys)
{
    if (fieldName.Contains("#"))
    {
        if (fieldName.Contains("."))
        {
            string[] names = fieldName.Split(new string[] { "." }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
            if (names.Last().Contains("#"))
            {
                changedFields.Add(fieldName, String.Format("{0}.{1}", String.Join(".", names, 0, names.Length - 1), names.Last().Replace("#", "")));
            }
        }
        else
        {
            changedFields.Add(fieldName, fieldName.Replace("#", ""));
        }
    }
}
foreach (string oldName in changedFields.Keys)
{
    stamper.AcroFields.RenameField(oldName, changedFields[oldName]);
}
```